# How to do datetime subtraction in Python based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[Sample Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6NEY.png)

I want to add a column that calculates the days since the last game was played (i.e. the difference between the GAME_DATE of the row and the GAME_DATE of the previous game).

So the result should be:

[Sample Dataframe Plus Desired New Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGiYj.png)

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file, open('file_copy.txt', 'w') as file_to_write:
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        line = line.rstrip('\r').rstrip('\n')
        if i == 0:
            file_to_write.write(line + '    DAYS_SINCE_LAST_GAME' + '\n')
        else:
            file_to_write.write(line + '   nan' + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is in `df`:

```
df.GAME_DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.GAME_DATE)

# Create a new column
df['DAYS_SINCE_LAST_GAME'] = None
res = list(df.groupby(df.PLAYER).GAME_DATE)

for i in range(len(res)):
    df.loc[df.PLAYER == res[i][0], 'DAYS_SINCE_LAST_GAME'] = \
                res[i][1].diff().replace(0, pd.NaT).fillna(None, 'ffill').dt.days
```

It basically groups the data by player and calculates time difference and fills in the difference. The last part is left for the reader to exercise.